# Error bootstrapping makefile fragments while building libjpeg/9d with Conan

Tags: c++, libjpeg, conan

I have been trying for several days to install OpenCV with Conan (on Windows 10). However, the installation is failing on building the `libjpeg/9d` dependency.

Conan profile:

```
[settings] 
arch=x86_64  
arch_build=x86_64    
build_type=Debug     
compiler=gcc
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
compiler.version=8
os=Windows
os_build=Windows
[options]
[build_requires]
[env]
```

The used command:

```
conan install .. --profile vslamprofile --build=missing
```

The part of the logs related to the error:

```
libjpeg/9d: configure: creating ./config.status
libjpeg/9d: config.status: creating Makefile
libjpeg/9d: config.status: creating libjpeg.pc
libjpeg/9d: config.status: creating jconfig.h
libjpeg/9d: config.status: executing depfiles commands
libjpeg/9d: config.status: error: in /c/users/username/.conan/data/libjpeg/9d/_/_/build/2e90c2fe2f69846019f521f2004427fb191035af':
libjpeg/9d: config.status: error: Something went wrong bootstrapping makefile fragments
libjpeg/9d:     for automatic dependency tracking.  Try re-running configure with the
libjpeg/9d:     '--disable-dependency-tracking' option to at least be able to build
libjpeg/9d:     the package (albeit without support for automatic dependency tracking).
libjpeg/9d: See `config.log' for more details
libjpeg/9d: configure: WARNING: cache variable lt_cv_path_LD contains a newline
libjpeg/9d:
libjpeg/9d: ERROR: Package '2e90c2fe2f69846019f521f2004427fb191035af' build failed
libjpeg/9d: WARN: Build folder C:\Users\username\.conan\data\libjpeg\9d\_\_\build\2e90c2fe2f69846019f521f2004427fb191035af
ERROR: libjpeg/9d: Error in build() method, line 100
autotools = self._configure_autotools()
while calling '_configure_autotools', line 88
self._autotools.configure(configure_dir=self._source_subfolder, args=config_args)
ConanException: Error 1 while executing /c/users/username/.conan/data/libjpeg/9d/_/_/build/2e90c2fe2f69846019f521f2004427fb191035af/source_subfolder/configure --prefix=/c/users/username/.conan/data/libjpeg/9d/_/_/package/2e90c2fe2f69846019f521f2004427fb191035af --enable-shared=no --enable-static=yes --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32
```

I have found several people with the similar error (not while installing OpenCV though) but I have not managed to find any solution.

```
## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

<...>
conftest.c:11:10: fatal error: ac_nonexistent.h: No such file or directory
 #include <ac_nonexistent.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
configure:4415: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "libjpeg"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libjpeg"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "9.4.0"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "libjpeg 9.4.0"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "libjpeg"
| #define VERSION "9.4.0"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <ac_nonexistent.h>
configure:4440: result: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -E
configure:4460: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -E -DLIBJPEG_BUILDING conftest.c
configure:4460: $? = 0
configure:4474: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -E -DLIBJPEG_BUILDING conftest.c
conftest.c:11:10: fatal error: ac_nonexistent.h: No such file or directory
 #include <ac_nonexistent.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
configure:4474: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "libjpeg"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libjpeg"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "9.4.0"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "libjpeg 9.4.0"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "libjpeg"
| #define VERSION "9.4.0"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <ac_nonexistent.h>
configure:4503: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:4525: result: yes
configure:4534: checking whether ln -s works
configure:4541: result: no, using cp -pR
configure:4551: checking for x86_64-w64-mingw32-ar
configure:4581: result: no
configure:4551: checking for x86_64-w64-mingw32-lib
configure:4581: result: no
configure:4551: checking for x86_64-w64-mingw32-link
configure:4581: result: no
configure:4595: checking for ar
configure:4611: found /c/.conan/42de2d/1/bin/usr/bin/ar
configure:4622: result: ar
configure:4648: checking the archiver (ar) interface
configure:4664: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -m64 -g -DLIBJPEG_BUILDING conftest.c >&5
configure:4664: $? = 0
configure:4666: ar cru libconftest.a conftest.o >&5
configure:4669: $? = 0
configure:4697: result: ar
configure:4726: checking if LD -Wl,--version-script works
configure:4750: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -m64 -g -DLIBJPEG_BUILDING -m64 -Wl,--version-script=conftest.map conftest.c  >&5
configure:4750: $? = 0
configure:4759: result: yes
configure:4772: checking for function prototypes
configure:4792: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -m64 -g -DLIBJPEG_BUILDING conftest.c >&5
configure:4792: $? = 0
configure:4800: result: yes
configure:4821: checking for grep that handles long lines and -e
configure:4879: result: /c/.conan/42de2d/1/bin/usr/bin/grep
configure:4884: checking for egrep
configure:4946: result: /c/.conan/42de2d/1/bin/usr/bin/grep -E
configure:4951: checking for ANSI C header files
configure:4971: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -m64 -g -DLIBJPEG_BUILDING conftest.c >&5
configure:4971: $? = 0
configure:5044: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -m64 -g -DLIBJPEG_BUILDING -m64 conftest.c  >&5
configure:5044: $? = 0
configure:5044: ./conftest.exe
configure:5044: $? = 0
configure:5055: result: yes
configure:5068: checking for sys/types.h
configure:5068: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -m64 -g -DLIBJPEG_BUILDING conftest.c >&5
configure:5068: $? = 0
configure:5068: result: yes
configure:5068: checking for sys/stat.h
configure:5068: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -m64 -g -DLIBJPEG_BUILDING conftest.c >&5
configure:5068: $? = 0
configure:5068: result: yes
configure:5068: checking for stdlib.h
configure:5068: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -m64 -g -DLIBJPEG_BUILDING conftest.c >&5
configure:5068: $? = 0
configure:5068: result: yes
configure:5068: checking for string.h
configure:5068: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -m64 -g -DLIBJPEG_BUILDING conftest.c >&5
configure:5068: $? = 0
configure:5068: result: yes
configure:5068: checking for memory.h
configure:5068: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -m64 -g -DLIBJPEG_BUILDING conftest.c >&5
configure:5068: $? = 0
configure:5068: result: yes
configure:5068: checking for strings.h
configure:5068: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -m64 -g -DLIBJPEG_BUILDING conftest.c >&5
configure:5068: $? = 0
configure:5068: result: yes
configure:5068: checking for inttypes.h
configure:5068: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -m64 -g -DLIBJPEG_BUILDING conftest.c >&5
configure:5068: $? = 0
configure:5068: result: yes
configure:5068: checking for stdint.h
configure:5068: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -m64 -g -DLIBJPEG_BUILDING conftest.c >&5
configure:5068: $? = 0
configure:5068: result: yes
configure:5068: checking for unistd.h
configure:5068: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -m64 -g -DLIBJPEG_BUILDING conftest.c >&5
configure:5068: $? = 0
configure:5068: result: yes
configure:5083: checking stddef.h usability
configure:5083: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -m64 -g -DLIBJPEG_BUILDING conftest.c >&5
configure:5083: $? = 0
configure:5083: result: yes
configure:5083: checking stddef.h presence
configure:5083: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -E -DLIBJPEG_BUILDING conftest.c
configure:5083: $? = 0
configure:5083: result: yes
configure:5083: checking for stddef.h
configure:5083: result: yes
configure:5083: checking for stdlib.h
configure:5083: result: yes
configure:5083: checking locale.h usability
configure:5083: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -m64 -g -DLIBJPEG_BUILDING conftest.c >&5
configure:5083: $? = 0
configure:5083: result: yes
configure:5083: checking locale.h presence
configure:5083: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -E -DLIBJPEG_BUILDING conftest.c
configure:5083: $? = 0
configure:5083: result: yes
configure:5083: checking for locale.h
configure:5083: result: yes
configure:5093: checking for string.h
configure:5093: result: yes
configure:5106: checking for size_t
configure:5133: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -m64 -g -DLIBJPEG_BUILDING conftest.c >&5
configure:5133: $? = 0
configure:5139: result: yes
configure:5175: checking for type unsigned char
configure:5188: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -m64 -g -DLIBJPEG_BUILDING conftest.c >&5
configure:5188: $? = 0
configure:5189: result: yes
configure:5200: checking for type unsigned short
configure:5213: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -m64 -g -DLIBJPEG_BUILDING conftest.c >&5
configure:5213: $? = 0
configure:5214: result: yes
configure:5225: checking for type void
configure:5259: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -m64 -g -DLIBJPEG_BUILDING conftest.c >&5
configure:5259: $? = 0
configure:5260: result: yes
configure:5270: checking for an ANSI C-conforming const
configure:5336: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -m64 -g -DLIBJPEG_BUILDING conftest.c >&5
configure:5336: $? = 0
configure:5343: result: yes
configure:5353: checking for inline
configure:5368: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -m64 -g -DLIBJPEG_BUILDING conftest.c >&5
configure:5368: $? = 0
configure:5406: result: __inline__
configure:5415: checking for broken incomplete types
configure:5428: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -m64 -g -DLIBJPEG_BUILDING conftest.c >&5
configure:5428: $? = 0
configure:5429: result: ok
configure:5441: checking for short external names
configure:5457: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -m64 -g -DLIBJPEG_BUILDING -m64 conftest.c  >&5
configure:5457: $? = 0
configure:5458: result: ok
configure:5471: checking to see if char is signed
configure:5508: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -m64 -g -DLIBJPEG_BUILDING -m64 conftest.c  >&5
configure:5508: $? = 0
configure:5508: ./conftest.exe
configure:5508: $? = 1
configure: program exited with status 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "libjpeg"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libjpeg"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "9.4.0"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "libjpeg 9.4.0"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "libjpeg"
| #define VERSION "9.4.0"
| #define HAVE_PROTOTYPES 1
| #define STDC_HEADERS 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
| #define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
| #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
| #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDDEF_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
| #define HAVE_LOCALE_H 1
| #define HAVE_UNSIGNED_CHAR 1
| #define HAVE_UNSIGNED_SHORT 1
| #define INLINE __inline__
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| #ifdef HAVE_STDLIB_H
| #include <stdlib.h>
| #endif
| #include <stdio.h>
| #ifdef HAVE_PROTOTYPES
| int is_char_signed (int arg)
| #else
| int is_char_signed (arg)
|      int arg;
| #endif
| {
|   if (arg == 189) {       /* expected result for unsigned char */
|     return 0;         /* type char is unsigned */
|   }
|   else if (arg != -67) {  /* expected result for signed char */
|     printf("Hmm, it seems 'char' is not eight bits wide on your machine.\n");
|     printf("I fear the JPEG software will not work at all.\n\n");
|   }
|   return 1;           /* assume char is signed otherwise */
| }
| char signed_char_check = (char) (-67);
| int main() {
|   exit(is_char_signed((int) signed_char_check));
| }
configure:5515: result: yes
configure:5523: checking to see if right shift is signed
configure:5563: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -m64 -g -DLIBJPEG_BUILDING -m64 conftest.c  >&5
configure:5563: $? = 0
configure:5563: ./conftest.exe
configure:5563: $? = 1
configure: program exited with status 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "libjpeg"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libjpeg"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "9.4.0"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "libjpeg 9.4.0"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "libjpeg"
| #define VERSION "9.4.0"
| #define HAVE_PROTOTYPES 1
| #define STDC_HEADERS 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
| #define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
| #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
| #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDDEF_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
| #define HAVE_LOCALE_H 1
| #define HAVE_UNSIGNED_CHAR 1
| #define HAVE_UNSIGNED_SHORT 1
| #define INLINE __inline__
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| #ifdef HAVE_STDLIB_H
| #include <stdlib.h>
| #endif
| #include <stdio.h>
| #ifdef HAVE_PROTOTYPES
| int is_shifting_signed (long arg)
| #else
| int is_shifting_signed (arg)
|      long arg;
| #endif
| /* See whether right-shift on a long is signed or not. */
| {
|   long res = arg >> 4;
| 
|   if (res == -0x7F7E80CL) {   /* expected result for signed shift */
|     return 1;         /* right shift is signed */
|   }
|   /* see if unsigned-shift hack will fix it. */
|   /* we can't just test exact value since it depends on width of long... */
|   res |= (~0L) << (32-4);
|   if (res == -0x7F7E80CL) {   /* expected result now? */
|     return 0;         /* right shift is unsigned */
|   }
|   printf("Right shift isn't acting as I expect it to.\n");
|   printf("I fear the JPEG software will not work at all.\n\n");
|   return 0;           /* try it with unsigned anyway */
| }
| int main() {
|   exit(is_shifting_signed(-0x7F7E80B1L));
| }
configure:5570: result: yes
configure:5578: checking to see if fopen accepts b spec
configure:5597: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -m64 -g -DLIBJPEG_BUILDING -m64 conftest.c  >&5
configure:5597: $? = 0
configure:5597: ./conftest.exe
configure:5597: $? = 0
configure:5598: result: yes
configure:5620: checking for x86_64-w64-mingw32-as
configure:5650: result: no
configure:5660: checking for as
configure:5676: found /c/.conan/42de2d/1/bin/usr/bin/as
configure:5687: result: as
configure:5712: checking for x86_64-w64-mingw32-dlltool
configure:5742: result: no
configure:5752: checking for dlltool
configure:5768: found /c/.conan/42de2d/1/bin/usr/bin/dlltool
configure:5779: result: dlltool
configure:5804: checking for x86_64-w64-mingw32-objdump
configure:5834: result: no
configure:5844: checking for objdump
configure:5860: found /c/.conan/42de2d/1/bin/usr/bin/objdump
configure:5871: result: objdump
configure:5962: checking how to print strings
configure:5989: result: printf
configure:6010: checking for a sed that does not truncate output
configure:6074: result: /c/.conan/42de2d/1/bin/usr/bin/sed
configure:6092: checking for fgrep
configure:6154: result: /c/.conan/42de2d/1/bin/usr/bin/grep -F
configure:6189: checking for ld used by x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
configure:6256: result: C:/Program
Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe
configure:6263: checking if the linker (C:/Program
Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe) is GNU ld
configure:6278: result: no
configure:6290: checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)
configure:6344: result: /c/.conan/42de2d/1/bin/usr/bin/nm -B
configure:6474: checking the name lister (/c/.conan/42de2d/1/bin/usr/bin/nm -B) interface
configure:6481: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -m64 -g -DLIBJPEG_BUILDING conftest.c >&5
configure:6484: /c/.conan/42de2d/1/bin/usr/bin/nm -B "conftest.o"
configure:6487: output
0000000000000000 b .bss
0000000000000000 d .data
0000000000000000 N .debug_abbrev
0000000000000000 N .debug_aranges
0000000000000000 N .debug_info
0000000000000000 N .debug_line
0000000000000000 r .rdata$zzz
0000000000000000 t .text
0000000000000000 B some_variable
configure:6494: result: BSD nm
configure:6498: checking the maximum length of command line arguments
configure:6629: result: 8192
configure:6677: checking how to convert x86_64-w64-mingw32 file names to x86_64-w64-mingw32 format
configure:6717: result: func_convert_file_msys_to_w32
configure:6724: checking how to convert x86_64-w64-mingw32 file names to toolchain format
configure:6744: result: func_convert_file_msys_to_w32
configure:6751: checking for C:/Program
Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe option to reload object files
configure:6758: result: -r
configure:6792: checking for x86_64-w64-mingw32-objdump
configure:6819: result: objdump
configure:6888: checking how to recognize dependent libraries
configure:7088: result: file_magic ^x86 archive import|^x86 DLL
configure:7133: checking for x86_64-w64-mingw32-dlltool
configure:7160: result: dlltool
configure:7230: checking how to associate runtime and link libraries
configure:7257: result: func_cygming_dll_for_implib
configure:7273: checking for x86_64-w64-mingw32-ar
configure:7300: result: ar
configure:7381: checking for archiver @FILE support
configure:7398: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -m64 -g -DLIBJPEG_BUILDING conftest.c >&5
configure:7398: $? = 0
configure:7401: ar cru libconftest.a @conftest.lst >&5
configure:7404: $? = 0
configure:7409: ar cru libconftest.a @conftest.lst >&5
ar: conftest.o: No such file or directory
configure:7412: $? = 1
configure:7424: result: @
configure:7442: checking for x86_64-w64-mingw32-strip
configure:7472: result: no
configure:7482: checking for strip
configure:7498: found /c/.conan/42de2d/1/bin/usr/bin/strip
configure:7509: result: strip
configure:7541: checking for x86_64-w64-mingw32-ranlib
configure:7571: result: no
configure:7581: checking for ranlib
configure:7597: found /c/.conan/42de2d/1/bin/usr/bin/ranlib
configure:7608: result: ranlib
configure:7710: checking command to parse /c/.conan/42de2d/1/bin/usr/bin/nm -B output from x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc object
configure:7863: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -m64 -g -DLIBJPEG_BUILDING conftest.c >&5
configure:7866: $? = 0
configure:7870: /c/.conan/42de2d/1/bin/usr/bin/nm -B conftest.o \| sed -n -e 's/^.*[ ]\([ABCDGIRSTW][ABCDGIRSTW]*\)[ ][ ]*\([_A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]*\)\{0,1\}$/\1 \2 \2/p' | sed '/ __gnu_lto/d' \> conftest.nm
configure:7873: $? = 0
configure:7939: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -m64 -g -DLIBJPEG_BUILDING -m64 conftest.c conftstm.o >&5
configure:7942: $? = 0
configure:7980: result: ok
configure:8027: checking for sysroot
configure:8057: result: no
configure:8064: checking for a working dd
configure:8102: result: /c/.conan/42de2d/1/bin/usr/bin/dd
configure:8106: checking how to truncate binary pipes
configure:8121: result: /c/.conan/42de2d/1/bin/usr/bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
configure:8410: checking for x86_64-w64-mingw32-mt
configure:8440: result: no
configure:8450: checking for mt
configure:8480: result: no
configure:8500: checking if : is a manifest tool
configure:8506: : '-?'
configure:8514: result: no
configure:9188: checking for dlfcn.h
configure:9188: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -m64 -g -DLIBJPEG_BUILDING conftest.c >&5
conftest.c:62:10: fatal error: dlfcn.h: No such file or directory
 #include <dlfcn.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
configure:9188: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "libjpeg"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libjpeg"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "9.4.0"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "libjpeg 9.4.0"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "libjpeg"
| #define VERSION "9.4.0"
| #define HAVE_PROTOTYPES 1
| #define STDC_HEADERS 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
| #define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
| #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
| #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDDEF_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
| #define HAVE_LOCALE_H 1
| #define HAVE_UNSIGNED_CHAR 1
| #define HAVE_UNSIGNED_SHORT 1
| #define INLINE __inline__
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <stdio.h>
| #ifdef HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H
| # include <sys/types.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_SYS_STAT_H
| # include <sys/stat.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef STDC_HEADERS
| # include <stdlib.h>
| # include <stddef.h>
| #else
| # ifdef HAVE_STDLIB_H
| #  include <stdlib.h>
| # endif
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_STRING_H
| # if !defined STDC_HEADERS && defined HAVE_MEMORY_H
| #  include <memory.h>
| # endif
| # include <string.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_STRINGS_H
| # include <strings.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_INTTYPES_H
| # include <inttypes.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_STDINT_H
| # include <stdint.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_UNISTD_H
| # include <unistd.h>
| #endif
| 
| #include <dlfcn.h>
configure:9188: result: no
configure:9442: checking for objdir
configure:9457: result: .libs
configure:9717: checking if x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions
configure:9735: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -m64 -g -DLIBJPEG_BUILDING -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions conftest.c >&5
cc1.exe: warning: command line option '-fno-rtti' is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C
configure:9739: $? = 0
configure:9752: result: no
configure:10110: checking for x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc option to produce PIC
configure:10117: result: -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC
configure:10125: checking if x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc PIC flag -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC works
configure:10143: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -m64 -g -DLIBJPEG_BUILDING -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -DPIC conftest.c >&5
configure:10147: $? = 0
configure:10160: result: yes
configure:10189: checking if x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc static flag -static works
configure:10217: result: yes
configure:10232: checking if x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc supports -c -o file.o
configure:10253: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -m64 -g -DLIBJPEG_BUILDING -o out/conftest2.o conftest.c >&5
configure:10257: $? = 0
configure:10279: result: yes
configure:10287: checking if x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc supports -c -o file.o
configure:10334: result: yes
configure:10367: checking whether the x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc linker (C:/Program
Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe) supports shared libraries
configure:11626: result: yes
configure:11866: checking dynamic linker characteristics
configure:12684: result: Win32 ld.exe
configure:12806: checking how to hardcode library paths into programs
configure:12831: result: immediate
configure:13379: checking whether stripping libraries is possible
configure:13384: result: yes
configure:13419: checking if libtool supports shared libraries
configure:13421: result: yes
configure:13424: checking whether to build shared libraries
configure:13449: result: no
configure:13452: checking whether to build static libraries
configure:13456: result: yes
configure:13575: checking libjpeg version number
configure:13585: result: 9.4.0
configure:13617: WARNING: cache variable lt_cv_path_LD contains a newline
configure:13699: checking that generated files are newer than configure
configure:13705: result: done
configure:13736: creating ./config.status

## ---------------------- ##
## Running config.status. ##
## ---------------------- ##

This file was extended by libjpeg config.status 9.4.0, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  CONFIG_FILES    = 
  CONFIG_HEADERS  = 
  CONFIG_LINKS    = 
  CONFIG_COMMANDS = 
  $ ./config.status 

on DESKTOP-GGV5QKI

config.status:1114: creating Makefile
config.status:1114: creating libjpeg.pc
config.status:1114: creating jconfig.h
config.status:1328: executing depfiles commands
config.status:1405: cd .       && sed -e '/# am--include-marker/d' Makefile         | make -f - am--depfiles
/tmp/GmP09nS0:326: *** missing separator.  Stop.
config.status:1410: $? = 2
config.status:1414: error: in `/c/users/username/.conan/data/libjpeg/9d/_/_/build/2e90c2fe2f69846019f521f2004427fb191035af':
config.status:1416: error: Something went wrong bootstrapping makefile fragments
    for automatic dependency tracking.  Try re-running configure with the
    '--disable-dependency-tracking' option to at least be able to build
    the package (albeit without support for automatic dependency tracking).
See `config.log' for more details
```

Comment: Did you check config.log?

Comment: @AlanBirtles I'm very new to C++, so, to be honest, the logs did not really explain what is happening to me. I have attached the logs to the question (not all the logs though due to the limitation on the question size).

Comment: The best is to report this issue in https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index repository. Is it possible that the recipe is not prepared to build for gcc in Windows (I guess MinGW?), so please report the details of your compiler and tooling setup too. Maybe libjpeg doesn't compile at all in Windows-gcc, using Conan or not?

Comment: @drodri I have reported it a few days ago but I was hoping to at least find a workaround here in the meantime (other recipe, other compiler?..). But, at this point, I guess I would have to resort to the manual installation of OpenCV and all its dependencies.

Comment: Any specific issues you are not using the Visual Studio binaries? Now that the community editions are free, it works very smoothly. I have been using ``opencv/3.4.5@conan/stable`` this week with Visual Studio 15 2017 Community, and works without issues. In general, the support for packages using Visual Studio will be much better.

Comment: @drodri There is no specific reason. As I have mentioned, I am new to C++, and I did not think it would be an issue to use MinGw. Thank you, the provided recipe works without issue with Visual Studio compiler indeed. If you write it as a separate answer, I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: I just ran into this today on a raspberry pi4 running ubuntu server. The issue for me was that I needed to install the build essential package `sudo apt install -y build-essential`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very possible that the `libjpeg` library doesn't compile with autotools and/or makefiles in the MinGW tool suite. Even if it is a `gcc` for Windows, it is not like all the code is fully portable between platforms, and those autotools or Makefiles might do some assumptions of platform that are not correct in Windows.

In general, the Visual Studio toolchain (MSBuild, cl.exe) is better supported in Windows platforms by the community, could be considered the default to-go, especially nowadays that the Visual Studio Community editions are completely free.

The packages in [ConanCenter](https://conan.io/center/) are also typically (and most of them, the ones created from the [conan-center-index repo](https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index)) built and tested with Visual Studio (several versions), so the support is expected to be much better than the one for MinGW.

Answer (score 11):

I came here when searching for this specific error message when trying to configure libcurl. In my case, 'make' wasn't installed.

Also in my case, this was on RHEL 8.

Comment: This was the solution for me on Debian 11 (attempting to install guacamole)

Comment: Work for me on Ubuntu 20.04. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You likely made a modification to a Makefile.am that caused `autoreconf` and/or `configure` to fail. Run,

```
rm -f config.h* configure
```

to clean up, then run,

```
autoreconf; ./configure
```

to reconfigure. Of course, if you haven't undone the assumed, offending change to your `Makefile.am` in the meantime, you're going to end up in the same spot.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in a different context because of a missing libtool installation under Msys2.